# How can I decorate STI models with modularized decorators using Draper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, draper

I'm using Draper for general view-layer decorators.

I have some console-related, human-readability functionality I'd like to pull into new decorators.

My first thought was to put them in a module, e.g., `Human::XxxDecorator`, keeping them isolated from my normal view-layer decorators: they're just for `rails c` debugging/hacking/testing work.

This works fine at the top level; I can explicitly decorate a model with the namespaced decorator.

Now I need to decorate a collection of STI vehicles. I'm not sure what the best way to create vehicle-type-specific decorators in the *same module of decorators*, e.g., I have:

- `Human::CarDecorator`
- `Human::TruckDecorator`
- `Human::MotorcycleDecorator`

I'm not sure how to get from, e.g.,

```
pry » dfleet = Human::FleetDecorator.new(Fleet.find(1))
```

to its embedded collections of vehicles, each with an appropriate decorator from the `Human` module. The naive approach using `decorates` doesn't work; I get:

```
Draper::UninferrableDecoratorError: Could not infer a decorator for Vehicle
```

The combination of:

- Decorators from a specific module, and
- Appropriate decorators for the STI models

is throwing things off.

Before digging into the Draper decorator inference code (I'm only assuming that's the best place to start), is this a problem that's already been solved and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, remove the builtin decoration of your vehicles, and code yours:

```
def vehicles
  object.vehicles.map do |v|
    # logic to instantiate proper decorator
  end
end
```

---

Hack incoming:

```
module Human
  class FleetDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    decorates_association :vehicles, with: ::Human::VehicleDecoratorDispatcher
  end

  class VehicleDecoratorDispatcher < Draper::Decorator
    def initialize(*args)
      super
      @object = ... # here you build the proper decorator based on the rules on @object
    end

  end
end
```

But I doubt this is clearer...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the manual work implied by this, though; I know I could do all the work by hand.

Comment: good luck then, I doubt there is something straightforward and cleaner though

Comment: Yeah, I suspect you're right after looking further into the code :( That's too bad, though, because context-sensitive decorators would be cool.

Comment: well, yes and no, they'd be somewhat magical, I'm happy with plain code in this case

Comment: I'm okay with magic in my exploration code, although I have some other uses for this as well. But meh--was just hoping it wouldn't require any effort.

Comment: well, depending on what extend you want to give to your decorators, you could override the `decorate` method in your classes

Comment: oh, let me suggest some hack

Comment: I'll give this a shot; it's clearer at the decorator level, although I'm still not overly excited for obvious reasons. I think I basically want to have a the initial decorator decide the namespace for the association decorators. I may just end up extending the affected classes on console startup and skip Draper for this, though, from the looks of things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use constantize:

```
def dfleet
  dfleet_decorator_class.new(object.dfleet)
end

def dfleet_decorator_class
  "#{object.dfleet.class}Decorator".constantize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use decorates: . Here is an example: [CLICK](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/517)

Comment: Please see my comment in the OP regarding `decorates`.